# Set animation rotation repeat back for layout

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want creat aniamtion rotation before it rotaion from 0 to -30 and after from -30 to 0  so I created two file animation
xoay.xml

```html
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-30"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:duration="6000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

xoay2.xml

```html
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-30"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:duration="6000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

and in activity I start animation with code

```js
final RotateAnimation rotate= (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.xoay);
final RotateAnimation rotate2= (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.xoay_2);
```

and when I set

```js
myView.startAnimation(rotate); or myView.startAnimation(rotate2);
```

it run. Now I want when myView finish animation xoay.xml it will run xoay2.xml and when xoay2.xml finish it run xoay.xml...
I tried with code :

```js
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
s.addAnimation(rotate);
s.addAnimation(rotate2);
myView.startAnimation(s)
```

but it not run.
How I can do it? Thank you very much !

Comment: it will start both at once. you have to set delay for second or you must implement AnimationListner for first and start second after first ends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with `RotateAnimation`

```
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 30.0f);

// Set the animation's parameters
an.setDuration(6000);               // duration in ms
an.setRepeatCount(-1);                // -1 = infinite repeated
an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation

// Aply animation to image view
myView.setAnimation(an);
```

Answer (score 2):

**I will create for you Just copy it and apply on your project**

**Step-1:** Create Animation xml files

*rotate_1.xml*

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:duration="1200" />
```

*rotate_2.xml*

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:toDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:duration="1200" />
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDemo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
TextView tvDemo;
boolean isFirstTime;
RotateAnimation rotate;
RotateAnimation rotate2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvDemo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDemo);
    rotate = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_up);
    rotate2 = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_down);

    tvDemo.startAnimation(rotate);

    rotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            tvDemo.startAnimation(rotate2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    rotate2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            tvDemo.startAnimation(rotate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });


    isFirstTime = false;
    tvDemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFirstTime = true;

        }
    });
}
```

**I Hope this code will work for you**

**Thank you**

Comment: Thank you! I did it

Answer (score 1):

Better you user `Animators` instead

```
AccelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(((StoryHolder) holder).ivLike, "rotation", 0f, -30f);
rotationAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

ObjectAnimator rotationAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(((StoryHolder) holder).ivLike, "rotation", 0f, -30f);
rotationAnim2.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
rotationAnim2.setDuration(300);
rotationAnim2.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

animatorSet.play(rotationAnim).before(rotationAnim2);
animatorSet.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did it

Answer (score 1):

//ROTATION

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, View.ROTATION, 0f, 180f).setDuration(300).start();
```

//ROTATION Back

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, View.ROTATION, 180f, 0F ).setDuration(300).start();
```